# three.js weird artifacts overlapping box and plane

Tags: three.js, artifacts

I'm seeing the weird behavior when at certain zoom levels / angles.

[image]

But at other positions it looks fine.

[image]

Can anyone tell me what's going on here, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decreasing the far distance of the camera solved the problem:

```
THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, aspect, 100, 15000)
```